# Rotating display from the Linux kernel

Tags: linux, video

I have a Freescale i.MX6 ARM development computer with a display I would like to mount in portrait mode.  The display accepts a DVI input, which I'm driving with an HDMI output from the computer.  I tell Linux to use the HDMI port with the kernel argument:

```
video=mxcfb0:dev=hdmi,1280x800
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem you can turn it to portrait by simply passing `800x1280` (wouldn't that be nice!).  I would like the screen to appear to *all* of userland as an 800x1280 portrait screen; is this possible to set up using the kernel alone?

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68369/rotate-console-on-startup-debian is an interesting post which suggests the Linux Kernel may be able to rotate the frame buffer [ at boot ], so I wonder if a kernel argument like "video=mxcfb0:dev=hdmi fbconn=rotate_all:1" might work, or, from https://community.nxp.com/thread/330816 if you could use an alternative frame buffer which is rotated - "video=mxcfb1:dev=hdmi,1280x800"

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/237963/how-do-i-rotate-my-display-when-not-using-an-x-server suggests the same too